# Trade offs in window based design of FIR filter

Tags: finite-impulse-response, window-functions

Please find  attached snap of proakis dsp book. It shows rectangular window has minimum value of stop band attenunation and transition width and as we go on towards Hamming and Blackman window,stop band attenunation and transition width both parameters keep on increasing

While according to my understanding ideal filters have maximum stop band attenuation and minimum transition width so in our window based design we can have either maximum stop band attenuation(Blackman window) or  minimum transition width(Rectangular window) at one  time  but not both simultaneously so there is a trade off

[image]

```
clc
clear all
close all
ord = 20;%filter order
bnd = [0.6];%cutt off frequency
bw1 = fir1(ord,[bnd],'high',rectwin(ord+1));
bw2 = fir1(ord,[bnd],'high',blackman(ord+1));
fvtool(bw1,1,bw2,1);
legend('Rectangular window','blackman')
```

[image]

Comment: You're right that there's a trade-off between stopband attenuation and transition width, but what is your question?

Comment: If you are interested in window trade off the Wikipedia article is a surprisingly good starting point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

Comment: The Windows information assumes floating-point coefficients. In practical high-speed processing, you might use truncated coefficients. In that case, you need to get the shape of the filters after the truncation.